# React Navigation Stack Navigation Transition

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have a React Navigation Stack Navigation. Now when I click the button it zooms out a little bit, but I want it to slide to the right or left. How do I do this? :)

I have a normal Stack Navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From React Navigation Docs:

> horizontal - The gesture to close the screen will start from the left, and from the right in RTL. For animations, screen will slide from the right with SlideFromRightIOS, and from the left in RTL.

Read this for complete overview of Animations in V5:

[Stack Navigator Animations](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations)